# Eloquent query order by problem: always return SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I write down this scope in voyager

```
        return Auth::user()->hasRole('user') ? $query
                              ->where('employees.client_id', Auth::user()->client_id)
                              ->join('employees', 'formations.employee_id', '=','employees.id')
                              : $query;

but it return the following error
```

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `formations` inner join `employees` on `formations`.`employee_id` = `employees`.`id` where `employees`.`client_id` = 111 order by `created_at` desc)

```
then I change it to 
        return Auth::user()->hasRole('user') ? $query
                          ->where('employees.client_id', Auth::user()->client_id)
                          ->join('employees', 'formations.employee_id', '=', 'employees.id')
                           ->orderBy('employees.created_at','DESC')
                           : $query;
```

and I got this error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous 
(SQL: select * from `formations` inner join `employees` on `formations`.`employee_id` = employees`.`id` where `employees`.`client_id` = 111 order by `employees`.`created_at` desc, `created_at` desc)
```

it seem to me laravel need to put any default. Is it a bug? Can i fix somehow?

Answer (score 0):

your query for somereason has has it's own orderby clause and it has to be removed:

first: remove all previous orderby statments:

```
$query->getQuery()->orders = null;
```

then you can use it with the new orderby:

```
return Auth::user()->hasRole('user') ? $query
                              ->where('employees.client_id', Auth::user()->client_id)
                              ->join('employees', 'formations.employee_id', '=','employees.id')
                              : $query;
```

Comment: Thanks but nothing changed. Still the same error, not even a new one :) . Probably was a valid sintax in older laravel versions.